# Doctrine ManyToMany, find related and no related results

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity called tournament to which users can register to participate in.

The relationship between the two entities is ManyToMany and need to create a view of Symfony2 in which list all tournaments, with or without registered users so that they can join.

This is my DoctrineQueryBuilder

```
$em->createQueryBuilder('d')
   ->select('d, i, u')
   ->leftJoin('d.item','i')
   ->leftJoin('d.users','u')
   ->where('d.active = 1')
   ->andWhere('d.state = 1')
   ->orderBy('d.dateStart', 'ASC');
```

I also need to get the number of users who have joined the tournament.

Comment: and what is the problem ? Is there any error message ?

Comment: The problem is that i just recived the related tournament, and i want to get all tournaments

Comment: With this DQL i get the tournaments with users joined, i want to get all the tournaments

Comment: Have you tried $em->getRepository('MyTournamentsEntityName')->findAll(); ?

Comment: The DQL must meet a minimum of optimization, I can not afford this query generates another query to capture the results of registered users per record

Comment: Are you trying to just get the number of users per active tournament?

Comment: No, i need to get all tournaments and the number of the users joined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Preamble**

There are various ways to achieve what you want. You can create a sub-query to do the count, however a simpler solution is to let doctrine handle this for you.

The solution described below is based on Doctrine lazy/eager loading capability. When doctrine loads an entity, it will also populate it's associations, either lazily or eagerly (default is lazy).

**Solution**

Assuming your `Tournament` entity maps the users association as a `ManyToMany` relation. You can create a new method which counts your `Tournament->users`.

ManyToMany associations would populate the entity property (in this cases `$users`) with an ArrayCollection.

A method called `countUsers` would do the trick, example implementation below:

```
...
class Tournament {
...
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User")
 * @JoinTable(name="tournament_users",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="tournament_id", referencedColumnName="id"}
 *      )
 **/
private $users;
...
public function countUsers(){
    return $this->users->count();
}
```

In the view when iterating over the collection of tournaments, simply call the `$tournament->countUsers()` method to display the count.

**References:**

*ArrayCollection:* http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.1/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html

Comment: Its the same if im on Twig template use length function :(

Comment: Using `length` won't show anything if the property is private (which is recommended). Have you tried the solution above?